# How to save a Plotly graph in a ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I understand that it is possible to export a Plotly graph, and that I can display it.

While sharing notebooks, the matplotlib plots remain intact in the Jupyter Notebooks, however, the Plotly graphs do not. They simply disappear

I understand that the Plotly graph is browser rendered, but is there any way I can store the graph in the ipynb file when I export it?

Is there any way that I can display the Plotly graph, just like the matplotlib graph?

[image: What I’m trying to achieve]

Edit: As suggested in an answer, I tried to save it to a figure object, and display that, but no luck there either :/

[image: I tried to use an object to store it as well]

Answer (score -3):

[image]If you put the code for a series of graphs in a single cell, execute it and save it, I think it will be displayed the next time you open it.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris() # iris is a pandas DataFrame
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn’t seem to work. I have added a supporting image in the question section as well

Comment: If I include 'fig.show()' from the library import, doesn't it show up?

Comment: i did, and I even included another image showing the same in the question. Still didn't show up in the ipynb preview

Comment: [plotly tutorial](https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/)Has this page been referenced and acted upon?

Comment: I have gone through the documentation there, yes. Again, plotly works as expected while 
working with the jupyter notebook, with the full intended functionality, but it does not store the output when I export my notebook as as ipynb file.

Comment: There's not much to deal with next to this.' Do you have the latest version of 'jupyter notebook' or 'jupiter lab' installed? If it's the latest, there's no batter.

Comment: I'm running it on jupyter notebook, yes, its the latest version, I tried this on jupyter lab with the extension as well. They all work flawlessly while running, but while exporting / sharing the file, they all disappear

Comment: This is the last one in my experience, and PLOTLY is up to date as well, isn't it? The latest version is plotly->4.8.0. If you want to run it with 'jupyter notebook', you need to install `pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"`.
Is 'notebook' and 'ipywidgets' also up to date at present?

Comment: they're both up to date as well. Oh well, I just gave up and exported my code to a html file instead of an ipynb file and the graphs work flawlessly

Comment: to be clear, I wanted the graphs to appear as they do now at https://sumuk.me/data-science but they appeared like they do now at https://github.com/sumukshashidhar/data-science/blob/master/AvacadoPrices.ipynb

Comment: I've seen your site in the comments show a graph of 'plotly'. The 'GIthub' one doesn't show the 'plotly' graph, it shows the installation history of 'plotly' in the pip. Are you aware of this too?

Comment: yes, as you can see, the GitHub one is an ipynb file that is saved. it shows matplotlib graphs, but not Plotly graphs. the exact file, when exported as html, saves the Plotly graphs, which is what I was trying to achieve with the GitHub one. basically, I want to achieve what I did on the site, on my GitHub version

Comment: Have you seen the contents of the file '.ipynb'? It is a text file in JSON format, so you can check it with an editor.
The graph in 'matolotlib' in 'ipynb' has saved the image as text. So you can check the graphs even on sites that don't have a running environment.
The 'plotly' graph is saved as a set of source and image text, so if you have an executable environment, the graph will be displayed. As I understand it.

Comment: ah, looks like it isn't possible to store it then, at least not in an ipynb file. other solutions online suggest that you export it to an image and read it with orca. in the notebook to display the image. so as of now there is no set solution.

Comment: My earlier comment was that if you compare the file for the 'matplotlib' graph with the file for the 'plotly' graph in your locally stored 'ipynb', you'll understand how it works.